# Entity extraction API for Android

Tags: android, nlp

I have extracted text successfully from image but now I have no idea how to extract the name, location, phone, and cell number from extracted text.

Here is some example text that was extracted.

```
Comsats Institute of Information technology,Abbottabad.
Dr Usama Ijaz bajwa 
Assistant Professor 
Phone:+92 321 6647911
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've tried to improve the grammar and formatting within your post so it is easier for others to read and understand what you are looking for. Unfortunately there isn't much that we can really help with unless you provide some code that you have tried. We can help answer questions within your code, but we cannot write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so that entity extraction is possible throw regex.You have to use Stanford entity extraction library to extract entity like name,location,time,...

http://nlp.stanford.edu/ner/

Comment: Is there any blog or tutorial available on how to use standford ner with Android?